# Magento caching crawler

Tags: magento-1.8, full-page-cache

I tried  to write a script to crawl my web store and generate fpc (lesti fpc) caching. Does anyone recommend any good scripts for doing that?

My script looks like this now, but I don't think its very efficient.

```
ALIAS='@ddc.production'
URL='http://mywebsite.com' 
wget $URL/sitemap.xml --no-cache --output-document - | egrep -o "http://$URL[^<]+" | while read line; do time curl -A 'Cache Warmer' -s -L $line > /dev/null 2>&1 echo $line
done
```

Is there any other good way to generate cache periodically every night?